# QueryDSL result mapping

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, querydsl

Day and Schedule have a 1 to N relationship. (oneToMany)

It works. However, when the Schedule table does not exist at all, ScheduleSummary with all fields filled with null will be included in schedules one by one. like this

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRsGe.png)

I want to make an empty list enter when schedule does not exist. Should I handle this in findDayScheduleListByTripId()? Or should I process it through separate logic in Service, Controller or DTO?

I tried CaseBuilder. But it doesn't works in transform() :(

```
@Getter 
public class DayScheduleDetail { 
    private Long dayId; 
    private Long tripId; 
    private LocalDate date; 
    private DayColorDto dayColor; 
    private List<ScheduleSummary> schedules

    @QueryProjection
    public DayScheduleDetail(Long dayId, Long tripId, LocalDate date, DayColor dayColor, List<ScheduleSummary> scheduleSummaries) {
        this.dayId = dayId;
        this.tripId = tripId;
        this.date = date;
        this.dayColor = DayColorDto.of(dayColor.name(), dayColor.getValue());
        this.schedules = scheduleSummaries;
    }
}


@Getter 
public class ScheduleSummary { 
    private Long scheduleId; 
    private String title; 
    private String placeName; 
    private String placeId; 
    private Coordinate coordinate;

    @QueryProjection
    public ScheduleSummary(Long scheduleId, String title, String placeName,String placeId, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.scheduleId = scheduleId;
        this.title = title;
        this.placeName = placeName;
        this.placeId = placeId;
        this.coordinate = Coordinate.from(latitude, longitude);
    }
}

public List<DayScheduleDetail> findDayScheduleListByTripId(Long tripId){

    return query.from(day)
            .leftJoin(day.schedules, schedule)
            .where(day.trip.id.eq(tripId))
            .orderBy(day.tripDate.asc(), schedule.scheduleIndex.value.asc())
            .transform(
                    groupBy(day.id).list(new QDayScheduleDetail(
                            day.id,
                            day.trip.id,
                            day.tripDate,
                            day.dayColor,
                            list(new QScheduleSummary(
                                    schedule.id,
                                    schedule.scheduleTitle.value,
                                    schedule.place.placeName,
                                    schedule.place.placeId,
                                    schedule.place.coordinate.latitude,
                                    schedule.place.coordinate.longitude
                            ))
                    ))
            );
}
```